# How would I handle a pythons equivalent of a dictionary in a dictionary in C++?

Tags: python, c++, data-structures

In python, I have this class that puts together a dictionary within a dictionary of values depending on some user input. This dictionary will be updated and used in later stages. In totality, it is supposed to look something like:

```
dict = {
          'string1': {
                        'string1':[1,2,3,4],
                        'string2':Bool,
                        'string3':Bool},
          'string2': {
                        'string1':[5,6,7,8],
                        'string2':Bool,
                        'string3':Bool}}
```

So, in C++ terms, what i know for sure is that I want to have a map that maps strings with **another** map which maps more strings to **either** a vector of **int** or **bools**.

Now i've heard that this can be done using `std::variant` but it seems as though I don't have it (I'm using AWS's Cloud9) and I'm not sure how else I can accomplish this.

Any ideas on better ways to do this? Or maybe how to actually get `std::variant`?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use C++17 or later to be able to use `std::variant`. If your compiler is `g++` or `clang++`, then add `-std=c++17`. If it's MSVC, add `/std:c++17`

Comment: Not sure how that relates to g++ but my compilers version is 7.5.0. Regardless, I don't seem to have it and I'm not sure how to get it.

Comment: `g++` 7.5.0 supports C++17, so by adding `-std=c++17` when compiling, you'll get access to `std::variant`

Comment: Is `-std=c++17` something you add within your script before compiling it? I tried it and got the following error `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘-’ token` in addition to the error resulting in `std::variant` not being declared in the scope.

Comment: `-std=c++17` is an argument to the compiler. Example:: `g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -o program foo.cpp bar.cpp`

Comment: Got you. On another note, can `map<string, variant<int, float>> args` be initialized directly? Or is it not possible since it defeats the whole point of `std::variant` which is that it doesn't know what to expect?

P.S The compiling aspect of it worked. But I just need to understand this bit of information.

Comment: Yes it can be initialized directly. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Mj9se69sv)

Comment: Is your example intentionally the same inner structure? `struct inner { std::vector<int> string1; bool string2; bool string3 }; std::map<std::string, inner> dict;` would work for your example

Answer (score 2):

You can use structure like this:

```
struct MixType {
  bool IsBoolType;
  bool BoolValue;
  std::vector<int> IntsValue;
};
```

And check value of IsBoolType.

Comment: So the idea is to instantiate this struct for each `string` (i.e. `string1` & `string2`) in the first map and change the values accordingly later on?

Would changing it be as simple as instantiating it and initializing it as something different? (P.S never fully understood structs)

Comment: You can use structure as variable with fields: MixType a; a.IsBoolType = true; a.BoolType = false; a.IntsValue.clear();